# How to use a function handle when number of inputs varies and symbolics have been used

Tags: matlab

and many thanks in advance for any help you can offer...

I am programming a general case scenario using Matlab, so the number of inputs to a function varies. Inputs take the form of number of elements in an input matrix.

(I am providing a simple toy example below to make my question clearer):

```
%# The code generates as many symbolic variables as necessary...

P1 = sym('P1')
P2 = sym('P2')
.
.
.
PN = sym('Pn')

%# I create a symbolic function of all the variables...

this  = (P1^2+P2^3+...+Pn^2)

%# I convert the symbolic function into a function...

that = matlabFunction(this)

%# Now I want to provide values for use in the calculation 
%# (I have a list of starting values for each P1...Pn)

other = that(???) --> 

%# ***Want to provide list of inputs that has as many values as the number 
%# of symbolic values I have created (which varies according to each case)****
```

I've looked through other questions, but maybe I'm not using the right search terms. Is there an elegant way to provide a variable number of inputs when I use the handle `that`?

Thanks so much for your help. 
I'm a rookie and appreciate it!!

Comment: Take a look at `varargin` and `nargin` in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using variables named in increasing order, use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html):

```
P = { sym('P1'), sym('P2'), ..., sym('Pn') }
```

Then you can use cell array unpacking to pass the items in the cell array as a list of parameters:

```
that = matlabFunction(P{:})
```

Note the difference between `P(:)` and `P{:}` (see [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-117.html)).

Comment: Thank you! I haven't had a chance to try this yet, but I appreciate you getting back to me so much. I'll let you know how I go...